# What's the deal with uTorrent 2.2.1?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I noticed people on reddit saying that uTorrent 2.2.1 is the GOAT client. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOAT = "greatest of all time". So this is not a technical term at all, it's just an opinion from somebody about uTorrent.

Of course, *you* may have a different opinion on uTorrent.

Comment: do you think it's safe to downgrade to it, considering it's so old?

Comment: @goatse I can confirm that it is safe to use. I used it myself for a while, as this torrent site I used required that specific version. It may lack many of the bells and whistles provided by more up to date versions, but its simplicity works.

Comment: @goatse - That would be an opinion, do your research, then based on that research form your own opinion.